# How to work with an Interface that inherits IDictionary and set desrialize object return type as that interface

Tags: c#, interface, json-deserialization, idictionary

Here I have one interface which inherits `IDictionary` and what I want is to get return type of that interface

1. Interface class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IClientSettings : IDictionary<string, string>
{

}
```

2. Code part of method where jsondata was deserialize to list dictionary

```
if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    DashboardJsonConverter jsonConverter = new DashboardJsonConverter();
    var keyValues = jsonConverter.DeserializeClientSettings(jsonData); //desrialize obj
    result.Dispose();//dispose response
    return (IClientSettings)keyValues;
}
```

3. Deserialize method

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> DeserializeClientSettings(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: here i have IClientSetting interface that inherit IDictionary<string,string> and httpresponse we get say jsonData was passed on DeserializeClientSettings where we get list<dictionary<string,string>> object so i want to return this object as IclientSettings lets say keyValuePair

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the C# type system to safely downcast one type to another.

`List<Dictionary<string, string>>` has no knowledge of `IClientSettings` so you can't cast that type to it.  You will need to create a concrete type that *does* implement that interface, and create a way to create that type from a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. What you could do is create an "adapter" type that wraps a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and passes through any method call to the underlying type.